# how to properly create a linked list

Tags: c

```
// creating a struct to store number of cd's, titles, and count
struct CD_type_node
{
    int cd_number;
    char title[20];
    int count;
    struct CD_type_node* next;
};

struct CD_type_node* mylist = NULL; // declaring a struct of type CD_type_node
struct CD_type_node* header;// head pointer for accessing linked list
header = NULL;

header = malloc(sizeof(struct mylist));
header = mylist;

while(header != NULL)
{
    header = header->next;
}
```

can someone tell me how to properly create a linked list and how to allocate memory dynamically because im getting an error: "invalid application of "sizeof" to incomplete struct mylist

Comment: Don't you mean `sizeof(struct CD_type_node)`?

Comment: Hah, you beat me to it, dark_charlie.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but when you assign `header` to the new memory you create then re-assign it to `mylist` which is NULL are you not creating a memory leak? Maybe you meant to assign `malloc` to `mylist`.

Comment: I think you're right, TheCapn.

Comment: The three assignments to header are a bit weird. Why setting it to NULL if it is assigned a new node and then set to mylist (which leaks the malloced node)? The malloc should be to mylist, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here

```
header = malloc(sizeof(struct mylist));
```

because `mylist` is a variable with type `struct CD_type_node*`, so

```
header = malloc(sizeof(*mylist));
```

is fine as is

```
header = malloc(sizeof(struct CD_type_node));
```

but `struct mylist` is wrong: it doesn't name either a type or a variable from which a type can be extracted.

Comment: I believe sizeof(mylist) is wrong since mylist is a pointer to CD_type_node... not an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sizeof(struct CD_type_node)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd extract the node creation into a function of this sort of form:

```
void AddNode(struct CD_type_node **head)
{
    struct CD_type_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct CD_type_node));
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}
```

For convenience you would probably want to pass in the other fields in the struct and get this routine to fill out the new node with those values.  But this routine gives you the idea of how to do the allocation and next pointer code.